# Initializing jQuery.load'ed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading part of my webpage using AJAX, in particular `jQuery.load()`. With this the usual jQuery pattern

```
$('.classname').click(...) // Handler
// or, working with bootstrap
$("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip() // Function
```

or similar obviously don't work any more, because they are called only when the page is loaded. I realize there is jQuery.on for the first example, but how would I implement the second?

Is there a simple (builtin) way to also apply these to `jQuery.load`ed stuff, or do I have to work around it myself? Seems like a problem a lot of people should be having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work around it yourself; but you can easily to this by calling `$("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()` in the callback for `load()`:

```
 $('#blah').load('/somewhere.html', function () {
     $('#blah').find('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
 });
```

Be sure to restrict the `tooltip()` call to only newly loaded elements, or you'll end up initializing tooltip multiple times per element (which *may* result in weird behaviour).

---

To avoid duplicating code you just need to define a helper function;

```
function initTooltip(root) {
    return $(root || document).find('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

Which allows you to init `tooltip`. The parameter is optional, and lets you restrict initialization to only descendants of the provided element, e.g.:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    initTooltip(); // equivilant to initTooltip(document);

    $('#blah').load('/somewhere.html', function () {
        initTooltip('#blah');
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()` looks like twitter bootstrap tooltip plugin, which is a noop if the tooltip is already instantiated on a given element. :P

Comment: How would I get around the duplicate code here (once in document.load, once in your code sample)?

Comment: Okay, I think i will go with an array of functions that will be called and register my stuff there, then I can have as many functions as I want. Strange that there isn't anything like this in jQuery, seems pretty standard...